# как сформировать выборку случайной величины с нормальным законом распределения и параметрами (0, 1) по заданной формуле, в Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа, numpy, статистика

Необходимо сформировать выборку случайной величины с нормальным законом распределения и параметрами (0, 1) по заданной формуле (9):

[image: формула 9]

Где Ri – независимые случайные величины

Формирую независимые случайные величины из нормального (гауссовского) распределения:

```
import numpy as np
R =  np.random.normal(0, 1, 12)
x = np.sum(R)-6
```

Но как привязать сюда формулу? и индекс kN не объяснён. Едтнственное что я знаю это то, что если Rj – независимые случайные величины, распределенные равномерно на интервале [0, 1], то последовательность

[image: формула 8]

распределена асимптотически нормально при N →∞ и имеет нулевое
математическое ожидание и единичную дисперсию. В частности при
N = 12 даёт формулу (9)